# Ошибка: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array, при получении значения из JSON массива

Tags: php

Есть такой JSON:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
  '1' => 
 stdClass::__set_state(array(
  'home' => '0',
  'away' => '0',
 )),
))
```

Хочу получить значение `home`:

```
echo $array['1']->home;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: `echo $array->{'1'}->home;`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie а почему мой вариант не срабатывает? можно более подробный ответ?) Буду благодарен.

Comment: Нельзя обращаться к объекту как к массиву, потому что это объект, а не массив. Можно привести к типу `array`, тогда можно будет

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказал @ArchDemon, у вас не массив, а объект. Он имеет подобную структуру:

```
$array = (object) ['1' => (object) ['home' => 'Значение']];
```

Можно получить "Значение" при правильном обращении к объекту:

```
echo $array->{'1'}->home;
```

Либо же преобразовать объект в массив и обратиться:

```
$array = (object) ['1' => (object) ['home' => 'Значение']];
$array = (array) $array;

echo $array['1']->home;
```